# Why one CID number maps to two UTF16 encodings in one CMap File?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I am debugging a strange problem of parsing PDF text using itext: the character "起" cannot be parsed correctly.

Finally I find that character (with CID code `2510`) been mapped to Unicode `<e44a>`. After reading the document for CID-Keyed Font (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5092.CID_Overview.pdf), I am quite confused why one CID number can be mapped to two different UTF16 encodings?

[image]

First occurrence: https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources/blob/master/Adobe-CNS1-7/CMap/UniCNS-UTF16-H#L12636

Second occurrence: https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/cmap-resources/blob/master/Adobe-CNS1-7/CMap/UniCNS-UTF16-H#L12636

And... the second one (the wrong one) wins.

```
...
<8d77> 2510
...
<e44a> 2510
...
```

==== The mentioned PDF file ====

PDF URL: [CK Hutchison 2018 Annual Report](https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2019/0409/ltn20190409587_c.pdf). The 13th character in line 3, page 128.

[image]

Result looks like this:

[image]

**This file works fine with PDFBox.**

Env: `itext7-core: 7.1.10`, `macOS 10.13.6`

Code:

```
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/hk-annual-report/00001.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputStream));
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(128);
    String s = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(page);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: My first reaction is "sounds like a bug"... or at least a data error.  As I think more on the subject, I recall that Unicode characters are are *characters* not *glyphs*.  Meaning, not appearance.  OTOH, I can't read any CJKV languages, so those two characters you're showing may have completely different meanings.  I wouldn't know.

Comment: Can you provide the PDF file in question?

Comment: @Ryan question updated.

Comment: What actually is your question? Do you merely want some explanation how some explanation *why one CID number can be mapped to two different UTF16 encodings?* Or do you want to know how to tweak iText 7 to return the Unicode code point you prefer?